# How to aggregate a column by a value on another column?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Suppose I have the following df.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A':['x','y','x','y'],
    'B':['a','b','a','b'],
    'C':[1,10,100,1000],
    'D':['w','v','v','w']
})

    A   B   C       D
0   x   a   1       w
1   y   b   10      v
2   x   a   100     v
3   y   b   1000    w
```

I want to group by columns A and B, sum column C, and keep the value from D which is the same row of the maximum group value of C. Like this:

```
A   B   C      D
x   a   101    v
y   b   1010   w
```

So far, I have this:

```
df.groupby(['A','B']).agg({'C':sum})

A   B   C
x   a   101
y   b   1010
```

What function do I have to aggregate column D with?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for indices of max values of `C` with `loc`:

```
#unique index
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df1 = df.groupby(['A','B'])['C'].agg(['sum', 'idxmax'])
df1['idxmax'] = df.loc[df1['idxmax'], 'D'].values
df1 = df1.rename(columns={'idxmax':'D','sum':'C'}).reset_index()
```

Similar solution with [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby(['A','B'])['C'].agg(['sum', 'idxmax']).reset_index()
df1['idxmax'] = df1['idxmax'].map(df['D'])
df1 = df1.rename(columns={'idxmax':'D','sum':'C'})
```

---

```
print (df1)
   A  B     C  D
0  x  a   101  v
1  y  b  1010  w
```

Comment: This saved me more than once now.

Just wanted to add that maybe `df.reset_index(inplace=True)` is needed before all this because more than one row might have the same index label for whatever reason.

Answer (score 4):

`set_index` before you group by

```
df.set_index('D').groupby(['A','B']).C.agg(['sum','idxmax']).\
    reset_index().rename(columns={'idxmax':'D','sum':'C'})
Out[407]: 
   A  B     C  D
0  x  a   101  v
1  y  b  1010  w
```